# Error starting selenium grid hub via powershell - VSTS/TFS

Tags: java, powershell, selenium, tfs, azure-virtual-machine

I'm struggling to start selenium grid on an azure VM via a powershell script in my build due to the following error....

> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Error: Unable to access jarfile selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar

The script simply contains `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub` and it runs fine locally. Java is installed on the VM.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks,

Comment: I created a `Windows Server 2012 Datacenter` VM on Azure with `Java 1.8.0_131` and ran the command you provided above. It worked fine on my side. So, could you tell us which version of Java and which version of windows you are using? Or you can have a try by running it on CMD.exe.

Comment: Hi Aaron. This is only an issue when running a build using the 'PowerShell on Target Machines' task. Like yourself, if I run the command in powershell directly on the Azure machine, it works fine. It also works fine if I do a WinRM connection to the azure machine and run it from my local machine. The azure server I have set up is windows server 2016 datacenter. It has the most up to date version of java installed (1.8.131) I suspect the issue is something to do with trying to run a .jar file during a build, but have no idea what the issue is. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

According to the script you provide, I suspect that you put the powershell script file in the same folder with "selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar" so you didn't need to specify the path to jar file in the script. However, you need to use absolute path for "selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar" file when you run the script from remote since the working folder is changed. Add the absolute path to the file or add "Set-Location" command in the script file to set the folder to the path where the jar file placed and then try again.

By the way, if you just call the "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub" command from the powershell script, you will keep waiting on the Remote PowerShell script step since the powershell script cannot be finished as the selenium server keeps running. I'd recommend you to start another process to run the selenium server like following:

```
Set-Location JarFileFolderPath
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {cmd /c start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub}
```

And make sure that stop the job after all your test is finished.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed response to this. I haven't had a chance to experiment with your script but I'm satisfied that it will probably fix things.

Comment: Hi Eddie. Unfortunately the suggestion provided doesn't work. I tried this both within a remote powershell session and in the 'PowerShell on Target Machines' build task and in both it failed to invoke the .jar file. I tried a variation `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {cmd /c start "C:\Selenium\Grid\SeleniumGrid.bat"} -Name "SeleniumGridHub"` and this did invoke the .bat file from a remote session, but not from within a build (Build task was marked as succeeded). Any other pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Konzy262 What do you mean "this did invoke the .bat file from a remote session, but not from within a build"?